# How to navigate and pull from an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am being given the function call `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);`. **I want to be able to pull from the last `2, 3` part after the initial object**, but I do not know how to go about this.

`return arr[6];` and `return arr[1][0]` both return nothing. I am expecting to see `2` or `2, 3` (Last two numbers)

I tried researching [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), but I think I was looking in the wrong place for my answer.

Here's my full code:

```
    function destroyer(arr) {
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Instead of getting the first array `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` 
I want to get the parts after the array:

[1,2,3,1,2,3]**,2,3**

Comment: This question isn't readily answerable in its current form. You'd be better off adding a complete code sample showing what you have so far (try to keep it brief, edit it down if necessary). And state very clearly what you're expecting to see and what you are actually seeing.

Comment: @Hargobind I hopefully have edited the question enough to clarify the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `destroyer` function is only taking one argument, but you're passing it 3.

You have two options:

1. **Use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to get an array-like of all the passed arguments**, you'll then need to combine that with a method like [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get only the second and third arguments. Additionaly since `arguments` isn't technically an array, you need to convert it to one before you can call a method like `slice`. My example uses [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) however that is only available on newer browsers.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  return Array.from(arguments).slice(1,3);
}

console.log('Result: ', destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],2,3));
```

2. **Add additional parameters to your function definition.** This is probably easier if you *know* you'll have exactly 3 arguments. And there are far fewer gotchas compared to using the magic `arguments` variable.

```js
function destroyer(a, b, c) {
  return [b, c];
}

console.log('Result: ', destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

try use ***arguments***
example

```
function destroyer(){var arr = []; arr.push(arguments[1]);arr.push(arguments[2]); return arr};
```

Comment: Instead of getting the first array `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` I want to get the parts after the array: [1,2,3,1,2,3] **,2,3**

Comment: try this :function destroyer(){var arr = []; arr.push(arguments[1]);arr.push(arguments[2]); return arr};